# Automate datepicker and timepicker using protractor

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

Automating a site using protractor where I am not able to get any idea how to automate given datepicker and timepicker.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: You are absolutely right and i did research and a lot practical thing and then if i didn't get any idea then i ll put it on community so we all are here to share the knowledge that's the motto of stackover flow.

Comment: Surely with your research, you have found some code or approach that you could try. The expectation is that you do that research, make some attempts, and then present that code here with a description of the errors you encountered or how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can Get date using 2 ways.I am showing you how you can do this

Using xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='month2']//div[.='19']")).click();`

Using JavascriptExecutor also you can input date

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('date-filed-top-date js-common-check-in-5 referrer_daterangepicker referrer_drp_start')[0].setAttribute('value', '2017-10-21')");
```

> //Replace date-filed-top-date js-common-check-in-5 referrer_daterangepicker referrer_drp_start to your class

Answer (score 0):

If clear() and sendKeys() won't trigger the datePicker dialog pop-up use option 1, otherwise use option 2.

1) use sendkeys to input date

```
function inputDate(targetEle, date) {
    targetEle.clear();
    return targetEle.sendKeys(date);
}

function inputStartDate(date) {
   return inputDate(element(by.css(#startDate)), date);
}

function inputEndDate(date) {
   return inputDate(element(by.css(#endDate)), date);
}

inputStartDate('09/20/2017 8:30 AM');
inputEndDate('09/23/2017 8:30 PM');
```

2) use javascript to set the attribute value of input text box

```
function inputDate(targetEle, date) {
   return browser.executeScript('arguments[0].value=arguments[1];', 
            targetEle.getWebElement(), date);
}

function inputStartDate(date) {
   inputDate(element(by.css(#startDate)), date);
}

function inputEndDate(date) {
   inputDate(element(by.css(#endDate)), date);
}

inputStartDate('09/20/2017 8:30 AM');
inputEndDate('09/23/2017 8:30 PM');
```

Comment: Its working fine.
But in another application the behaviour of datepicker is different so i tried to implement it there but it's not working

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
element(by.xpath("")).sendKeys("10/10/002018 03:00PM");
```